# Como agrupar resultados de uma query de linhas para colunas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, select, sql-select

Boa tarde,

tenho esta query

```
SELECT
                tblcliente.idCliente,
                tblclienterespostapre.resposta
                FROM
                tblcliente
                INNER JOIN tblclienterespostapre ON tblclienterespostapre.idCliente = tblcliente.idCliente
                INNER JOIN tblpergunta ON tblclienterespostapre.idPergunta = tblpergunta.idPergunta
                WHERE
                tblpergunta.idPergunta = 16 OR
                tblpergunta.idPergunta = 34 OR
                tblpergunta.idPergunta = 35 AND
                tblcliente.estado = 1
```

que me devolve este resultado

eu necessitava que em vez de me retornar 6 linhas em duas colunas me retorna-se duas linhas em 3 colunas, deste género:

```
Linha 1: 42 | andre da silva | 930000000 | adads@adasd.pt
linha 2: 43 | cliente numero 2              | telefone  | email |
```

Este é o meu modelo de base de dados

isto basicamente é uma aplicação que gere utilizadores, esses utilizadores são compostos por varias perguntas em que as perguntas podem ter varias caraterisitcas, como tipodepergunta, se é publica ou nao, se foi validada ou não, essas perguntas são dinamicas, ou seja pode ser adicionadas novas perguntas para todos os clientes.

é um bocado confuso :s

caso fosse possivel dar nomes às colunas também era uma mais valia

Obrigado

Comment: Pelo que consta já há um erro de modelagem de banco de dados, é importante ter uma flag para cada tipo, senão fica uma bagunça só.

Comment: agora faz mais sentido, pois tem id a pergunta e na resposta também..., vou refazer a query.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode esta utilizando um *cursor* para fazer isso.

veja o exemplo como ficaria.

```
declare @tabela table
(
    id int ,
    resposta varchar(100)
)

declare @usuario table
(
    id int ,
    nome varchar(100),
    telefone varchar(100) null,
    email varchar(100) null
)

insert into @tabela values
(1, 'joao'),
(1, '3232323'),
(1, 'joao@hotmail.com'),

(2, 'paulo'),
(2, '3232323'),
(2, 'paulo@gmail.com')

DECLARE  @id int
DECLARE @resposta VARCHAR(100)
declare @index int = 0;

DECLARE cursor_objects CURSOR FOR
select id,  resposta as nome from @tabela

-- Abrindo Cursor para leitura
OPEN cursor_objects

-- Lendo a próxima linha
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_objects INTO @id, @resposta

-- Percorrendo linhas do cursor (enquanto houverem)
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

   if(@index = 0)
        insert into @usuario values (@id, @resposta, '','')
    if (@index = 1)
        update @usuario set telefone = @resposta where id = @id
    if (@index = 2)
        update @usuario set email = @resposta where id = @id

    set @index = @index + 1;

    if(@index > 2)
        set @index = 0;

    -- Lendo a próxima linha
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_objects INTO  @id, @resposta
END

-- Fechando Cursor para leitura
CLOSE cursor_objects

-- Desalocando o cursor
DEALLOCATE cursor_objects

select * from @usuario
```

Answer (score 1):

O pessoal apresentou uma solução para o seu problema:

```
  # Versao estatica
  SET @id_perguntas = '16,34,35';
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(cli_resp.idPergunta = ', idPergunta, ', resp.resposta, NULL))',
           ' AS `', pergunta, '`'))
INTO @sql
FROM
  tblPergunta
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idPergunta, @id_perguntas)
ORDER BY idPergunta;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT
       cli_resp.idCliente,',
       @sql,
    'FROM tblCliente cli
       INNER JOIN tblClienteRespostaPre cli_resp
         ON (cli.idCliente = cli_resp.idCliente)
       LEFT JOIN tblRespostaPre resp
         ON (cli_resp.idRespostaPre = resp.idRespostaPre)
     WHERE cli.estado = 1 AND cli_resp.idPergunta IN (', @id_perguntas, ')',
    'GROUP BY cli.idCliente
     ORDER BY cli.idCliente');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[**Aqui está o exemplo funcionando**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ce48/1)

Comment: Ivan Ferrer, obrigado pela ajuda, mas uma flag como assim? pode me explicar? entretanto vou editar a pergunta e vou colocar o esquema da base de dadso que tenho a ver se ajuda ok?, mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: Flag é informar o tipo de dado que você quer alinhar em colunas. Para não se perder em uma linha extensa sem sentido.

Comment: Senão eu entendo que serve qualquer coisa, daí seria só fazer um contador de 3 blocos e pegar qualquer coisa e mostrar na horizontal.

Comment: experimentei a primeira query,, no entanto não funcionou, (Subquery returns more than 1 row), o problema é que vou ter várias perguntas, hoje podem ser 10 amanha podem ser 100 Obrigado pela ajuda Ivan

Comment: para ajudá-lo, eu abri uma pergunta, e espero que tenha uma resposta para o seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95415/como-agrupar-e-remover-as-linhas-com-valores-null-dessa-consulta-no-mysql