# Como agrupar e remover as linhas com valores "null" dessa consulta no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, stmt

```
CREATE TABLE tblCliente (
idCliente int(11),
estado int(1)
);

CREATE TABLE tblPergunta (
idPergunta int,
idCategoria int,
pergunta varchar(255),
tipoResposta tinyint(1)
);

CREATE TABLE tblClienteRespostaPre (
idCliente int(11),
idPergunta int(11),
idRespostaPre int(11),
privacidade int(1),
verificada int(1)
);

CREATE TABLE tblRespostaPre (
idRespostaPre int(11),
idPergunta int(11),
resposta varchar(255)
);


insert into tblCliente values
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1);

insert into tblPergunta values
(16, 1, 'qual o seu telefone?',1),
(34, 4, 'qual o seu email?',   1),
(35, 2, 'você é de são paulo?',1);

insert into tblClienteRespostaPre values
(1, 16, 1, 1, 1),
(1, 34, 2, 1, 1),
(1, 35, 3, 1, 1),
(2, 16, 4, 1, 1),
(2, 34, 5, 1, 1),
(2, 35, 6, 1, 1),
(3, 16, 7, 1, 1),
(3, 34, 8, 1, 1),
(3, 35, 9, 1, 1);

insert into tblRespostaPre values
(1, 16, '123456789'),
(2, 34, 'meuemail@xxx.com'),
(3, 35, 'sim'),
(4, 16, '568723658'),
(5, 34, 'ououo@ouou.com'),
(6, 35, 'não'),
(7, 16, '687678677'),
(8, 34, 'nonono@uol.com'),
(9, 35, 'Claro');

SET @sql = NULL;
SET @count := 0;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'CASE WHEN tblRespostaPre.idPergunta = ', idPergunta,' THEN \'', resposta,'\'
       ELSE  null END AS \'Resposta ',@count:=@count + 1,'\'')
  )
INTO @sql
FROM
  tblRespostaPre where idPergunta IN (16,34,35);

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tblCliente.idCliente,
                          tblPergunta.idPergunta,
                          ',@sql,' 
                  FROM tblCliente 
                  INNER JOIN tblClienteRespostaPre ON (tblClienteRespostaPre.idCliente=tblCliente.idCliente)
                  INNER JOIN tblPergunta           ON (tblPergunta.idPergunta=tblClienteRespostaPre.idPergunta)
                  INNER JOIN tblRespostaPre        ON (tblRespostaPre.idPergunta=tblClienteRespostaPre.idPergunta)
                  WHERE  tblPergunta.idPergunta    IN (16,34,35) AND tblCliente.estado=1 
                  group by tblPergunta.idPergunta, tblCliente.idCliente');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Código de exemplo: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8332c/15**

A ideia é colocar em formato de pivot (invertendo as linhas para colunas), essa consulta ele retorna na vertical as perguntas, mas teria que ser na horizontal:

```
SELECT cli.idCliente as ID_CLIENTE,
       perg.idPergunta as ID_PERGUNTA,
       resp.idRespostaPre as ID_RESPOSTA,
       perg.pergunta as PERGUNTA,
       resp.resposta as RESPOSTA
FROM   tblCliente cli  
       INNER JOIN tblClienteRespostaPre cli_resp
       ON (cli_resp.idCliente=cli.idCliente)
       LEFT JOIN tblPergunta perg
       ON (perg.idPergunta=cli_resp.idPergunta)
       LEFT JOIN tblRespostaPre resp
       ON (resp.idPergunta=cli_resp.idPergunta)
WHERE  perg.idPergunta in(16,34,35) AND cli.estado=1;
```

Comment: Você diz `null` em qualquer campo?

Comment: Sim, veja que ele está desalinhando.

Comment: a ideia é não repetir, tipo id 1,2,3... fazer tudo no mesmo nível.

Comment: Neste caso você iria remover todas as linhas? Pois em seu exemplo todas as linhas possuem pelo menos um valor `null`.

Comment: Eu editei para ficar mais claro..., o que eu quero é trazer todos só que alinhado pela ID do cliente.

Comment: Essa pergunta foi aberta para ajudar a solucionar esta questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95113/como-agrupar-resultados-de-uma-query-de-linhas-para-colunas/95143?noredirect=1#comment193317_95143

Comment: Não entendi onde você quer chegar. [Desta forma](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8332c/17) está ordenado pelo ID do cliente, mas não entendi a parte do `null`.

Comment: O null é um erro. Não era pra ter null, era pra ser tudo alinhado bonitinho. Veja que há duplicatas, mesmo sendo alinhado pela ID. era pra ter só 3 linhas.

Comment: E se você usar GROUP_CONCAT no campo das perguntas e GRUP BY nos demais campos do select ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se eu entendi sua pergunta direito você está tentando fazer essa consulta aqui:

```
SELECT
  cli_resp.idCliente,
  MAX(IF(cli_resp.idPergunta = 16, resp.resposta, NULL)) AS `Qual o seu telefone?`,
  MAX(IF(cli_resp.idPergunta = 34, resp.resposta, NULL)) AS `Qual o seu email?`,
  MAX(IF(cli_resp.idPergunta = 35, resp.resposta, NULL)) AS `Você é de são paulo?`
FROM tblCliente cli
  INNER JOIN tblClienteRespostaPre cli_resp
    ON (cli.idCliente = cli_resp.idCliente)
  LEFT JOIN tblRespostaPre resp
    ON (cli_resp.idRespostaPre = resp.idRespostaPre)
WHERE cli.estado = 1 AND cli_resp.idPergunta IN (16, 34, 35)
GROUP BY cli.idCliente
ORDER BY cli.idCliente;
```

### Resultado

[image: Resultado consulta]

---

Se a ideia era gerar o SQL da consulta dinamicamente a partir de uma lista de ids das perguntas você estava no caminho certo:

```
SET @id_perguntas = '16,34,35';
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(cli_resp.idPergunta = ', idPergunta, ', resp.resposta, NULL))',
           ' AS `', pergunta, '`'))
INTO @sql
FROM
  tblPergunta
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(idPergunta, @id_perguntas)
ORDER BY idPergunta;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT
       cli_resp.idCliente,',
       @sql,
    'FROM tblCliente cli
       INNER JOIN tblClienteRespostaPre cli_resp
         ON (cli.idCliente = cli_resp.idCliente)
       LEFT JOIN tblRespostaPre resp
         ON (cli_resp.idRespostaPre = resp.idRespostaPre)
     WHERE cli.estado = 1 AND cli_resp.idPergunta IN (', @id_perguntas, ')',
    'GROUP BY cli.idCliente
     ORDER BY cli.idCliente');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

#### [Exemplo funcional no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8332c/122)

---

**Fonte**: [SOen - MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12598120/664577)

Comment: Ivan, dinâmicas baseadas em que? Basta alterar a cláusula where da consulata que monta as perguntas e a cláusula where que filtra as respostas conforme seus critérios.

Comment: Esquece, ficou perfeito! Valeu!

Comment: Agora está perfeito, Anthony!

Comment: Obrigado Ivan e Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Esta query retorna as perguntas em linha.

```
select a.idCliente,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.idPergunta),
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct d.idRespostaPre),
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.pergunta),
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct d.resposta)
  from tblCliente a,
       tblClienteRespostaPre b,
       tblPergunta c,
       tblRespostaPre d
 where a.idCliente = b.idCliente
   and b.idPergunta = c.idPergunta
   and b.idPergunta = d.idPergunta
   and a.estado = 1
   and b.idPergunta in (16, 34, 35)
 group by a.idCliente
 order by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```